# Extraction of day, month and year from the date 4.5.6

Tags: python, datetime

Which function can I use to extract day, month and year from dates written in this manner 4.5.6 where 4 is the day, 5 is the month and 6 is the year (presumably 2006). I have already tried using dateparser.parse but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

```
day, month, year = map(int, '4.5.6'.split('.'))
```

And then add 2000 as necessary to the year.

You can then construct a datetime object with

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime(year, month, day)
```

While it would be logical to use `datetime.strptime`, the one-digit year messes things up, and the above will just work fine.

Comment: `datetime(*(a+b for a, b in zip((2000,0,0), map(int, '4.5.6'.split('.')[::-1]))))` in one go. expect people to complain about readability though.

Comment: @MrFuppes While perhaps enjoyable, as per per the Zen of Python: "Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex." I wouldn't be able to understand your code within a 10-second look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method:

```
import datetime

s = "4.5.6"
i = s.rindex('.') + 1
s = s[:i] + s[i:].rjust(2, '0') # Add padding to year
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d.%m.%y")
print(dt)
```

Output:

```
2006-05-04 00:00:00
```

With the resulting  `datetime.datetime` object, you can access plenty of information about the date, for example you can get the year by printing `dt.year` *(outputs `2006`)*.